# INSERT or UPDATE other than primary column in mysql

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a table with following columns

```
id -> VARCHAR (PRIMARY KEY)
data -> TEXT
user_id -> VARCHAR
```

I would like to insert into this table if row doesn't already exists. Else update the `data` column and leave everything else intact. Currently I am doing this

`REPLACE INTO collate(id,user_id,data)VALUE('$id','$user_id','$data')`. But this deletes the a row (if found) and then inserts again . It is server intensive

Comment: Please change your title from uppercase to normal case.

Answer (score 3):

As documented under [`REPLACE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/replace.html):

> [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/replace.html) is a MySQL extension to the SQL standard. It either inserts, or *deletes* and inserts. For another MySQL extension to standard SQL—that either inserts or *updates*—see [Section 13.2.5.3, “`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` Syntax”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Therefore:

```
INSERT INTO collate
  (id, user_id, data)
VALUES
  ('$id','$user_id','$data')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  data = VALUES(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check following URL
[insert-on-duplicate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) (INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax
)